# Control method called using variables

Tags: java, reflection

so I'm trying to combine multiple methods that sort an array based on different parameters for optimization. The entire method is the same except for this line:

```
for (int k = i; k >= 0 && currData.METHOD() <= playerData[k].METHOD(); k--) {

    //The stuff inside the method is the same
}
```

Where METHOD is being changed to different accessor methods, to control how the array is being sorted.

I did a little bit of searching and came across Java reflection (I'm not sure what it is though). Could someone explain how I could use that to solve my problem, or another better solution? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn about the `Comparator` class. You can write different `Comparator`s comparing the data based on different fields, and then sort using the appropriate one. By the way, you almost certainly don't want to be writing your own sort algorithm. `Arrays.sort` and `Collections.sort` are there for a reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the variables are stored, you can do something like this:

```
String what = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
System.out.println(what.getClass().getMethod(what).invoke(what));
```

If I enter the word *length* as my input, the output is 6. Because the code calls the function I enter on the string. They don't have to be the same variable though, you could do something like:

```
for (int k = i; k >= 0 && currData.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(currData)
<= playerData[k].getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(playerData[k]); k--)
```

You can also pass arguments to the functions, if you need to, it's the second parameter after the function name. Just make your variables equal to the function name you want called, and bob's your uncle, should work like a charm.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in the code. Could you explain it? I am trying to pass an argument to the function to control what method is called.

Comment: What the code does is call a method of a class on an object. It's the same as what you are doing when you use `currData.METHOD()`, but it is dynamic. METHOD would be a string, like `string m = "method";` and you use `currData.getClass().getMethod(m).invoke(currdata)`Which calls the method of that class with a name equal to the strings value, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use reflection here. Use polymorphism, it'll help.